# How do I get the file creation time with ansible on MacOS?

Tags: macos, ansible

I am trying to list a set of directories with their creation times in an ansible playbook on MacOS.

The problem I have is that the file and stat modules give you the "ctime" of a file, but on MacOS this is the time of last metadata change, not the creation date.

So for example this playbook:

```
- name: Get dirs and create dates
  hosts: localhost

  tasks:
  - name: make a list of dirs
    find:
      paths:
        - "/Users/me/Work/Customers"
      file_type: directory
      recurse: false
    register: projectdirs

  - name: Dump found paths
    debug:
      msg: "{{ shortname }} {{ date }}"
    loop: "{{ projectdirs.files }}"
    loop_control:
      label: "{{ item.path }}"
    vars:
      shortname: "{{ item.path | basename }}"
      date: "{{ '%Y-%m-%d' | strftime(item.ctime) }}"
```

This just lists todays date as "creation" date for the directory.

```
ok: [localhost] => (item=/Users/me/Work/Customers/Base) => {
    "msg": "basefarm 2021-08-23 1629699678.021843"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=/Users/me/Work/Customers/Acme) => {
    "msg": "Orange 2021-08-23 1629699678.5415485"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=/Users/me/Work/Customers/Foo) => {
    "msg": "VKB 2021-08-23 1629699679.0579438"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=/Users/me/Work/Customers/Bar) => {
    "msg": "LombardOdier 2021-08-23 1629699679.5856457"
}
...
```

I found out that the reason is of course that ctime is not the creation time on a mac...

Is there a way around this? I want the real creation date, but Ansible's stat module does not give me this. The creation date is available, as I can get it with `ls -ldU` for example.

So how do I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no way to do so without using shell command.

```
  - name: make a list of dirs
    find:
      paths:
        - "/Users/me/Work/Customers"
      file_type: directory
      recurse: false
    register: projectdirs

  - name: Get creation time
    shell: GetFileInfo {{ item.path }} | grep 'created:'
    loop: "{{ projectdirs.files }}"
    loop_control:
      label: "{{ item.path }}"
    register: directories

  - name: Dump found paths
    debug:
      msg: "{{ item.item.path }} {{ item.stdout.split('created: ')[1] }}"
    loop: "{{ directories.results }}"
    loop_control:
      label: "{{ item.item.path }}"
```

Gives me this result :

```
ok: [localhost] => (item=/Users/jeromeverdoni/stackoverflow/68888321) => {
    "msg": "/Users/jeromeverdoni/stackoverflow/68888321 08/23/2021 08:01:44"
}
```

Hope this is close enough to your expected behaviour.

*For reference, GetFileInfo output :*

```
╰─ GetFileInfo /Users/jeromeverdoni/stackoverflow/68888321     
directory: "/Users/jeromeverdoni/stackoverflow/68888321"
attributes: avbstclinmedz
created: 08/23/2021 08:01:44
modified: 08/23/2021 08:03:18
```